# How to configure Facebook Graph API to Get and Send messages to my application from facebook page

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am going to read the messages which are receiving to my `facebook` page and send verification to senders.

I have written a code to read messages using natural language processing method. but i am still struggling to get messages to my application.

I am using `visual studio 2013` and developing using `c#`. Please help me to configure callback url in Graph API get messages to my local PC:

[image]

Comment: You should probably show some relevant code you've made for others to help you faster

Comment: For Facebook to be able to send you updates, your server must be publicly reachable on the internet.